# Java: Extract string from a specific character '#' and separate it into array

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my Java code, I am trying to extract string from a specific character and separate it into an array. As for now, the specific character I am checking is '#'. Then once I extract the string, I want to separate the content into an array.

This is my Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String example = "\"abc\", 1, 2.0, #1;2;3, #4;5;6";
   String removed_openbraces = example.substring(example.indexOf("#") + 1);
   System.out.println(removed_openbraces);
}
```

In the above code, the ';' represents the split for the array content. There is two array in my current code. I tried a few ways but it seems, its not working at all. Any Java experts here to help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried `example.split("#")`?

Comment: You haven't pasted any of the stuff you tried. I suggest you add that, it gives us something to work with. Otherwise this is mostly just 'do my (home)work for me', which aren't great SO questions.

Comment: Actually, the above code, is the one I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not allowed to write `example.split("#")` in your program.

For a `String` containing multiple `#`s, you will need a loop.

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String example = "\"abc\", 1, 2.0, #1;2;3, #4;5;6";
        int start = example.indexOf("#") + 1;
        int end = example.indexOf("#", start);
        
        while(start < example.length() - 1)
        {
            String removed_openbraces = example.substring(start, end);
            System.out.println(removed_openbraces);
            start = end + 1;
            end = example.indexOf("#", start + 1);
            end = end > start ? end : example.length();
        }
    }
}
```